# How to keep bootstrap modal inside html form?

Tags: php, html, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to get data from inputs of modal and to submit into database. Form has also input fields that aren't inside modal. I wrote modal inside form but it keep going outsite it (Im watching in inspect element), so I can't get those data.
Is there any chance I make this working?

Pseudocode:

```
<form>
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="Name" />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Check students</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="checkbox" name="students[]" value="student1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="students[]" value="student2">
        <input type="checkbox" name="students[]" value="student3">
        <input type="checkbox" name="students[]" value="student4">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<!-- END MODAL -->

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="main-btn">Create</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It looks like you need to check how your jquery and bootstrap.js are configured.

Comment: I think Im just using regular jquery and bootstrap.js. What do you mean?

Comment: https://codepen.io/brooksrelyt/pen/oVgYwd  -  This is a working codepen using your code

Comment: Hmm, it could be!

Comment: Try that, also wrapping your entire snippet of code in a `form` element may be more difficult than putting the form into the modal. Maybe someone else can chime in but I think you may want to trigger the modal and then input the student information. I could be wrong though

Comment: By default, the positioning of bootstrap's modal is set to 'fixed'. Why don't you just use a regular textfield for the input? If you really want to  make it work, set the modal's positioning to absolute and set the form's positioning to relative - to make it its parent. From there, just adjust the position properties (top, left, right, bottom). Or if you want to treat the modal as a block, just set its positioning to 'relative'

Answer (score 3):

You should keep the  tag open and close before the modal.

```
<form id="myForm1">
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="Name" />
</form>
```

Then, add the attibute form to every input inside your modal.

```
<input form="myForm1" type="checkbox" name="students[]" value="student1">
```

Don't forget the submit button

```
[...]
<!-- END MODAL -->
<button type="submit" form="myForm1"  class="btn btn-primary" id="main-btn">Create</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I spent one day for this issue. Now i got cleared using your answer @Edoardo Lobbiani

Answer (score 0):

Any button inside form will automatically be considered as "submit" button

> If the button is a submit button (it's inside/associated with a 
> and doesn't have type="button"), specifies how to encode the form data
> that is submitted.

So i just added to the button that opens the modal the `type="button"` and it stopped from submitting the form.

Regarding the above answer - in my case the modal was outside the `<form>` already ... so i knew this wasn't it for me.